# Sending 6numbers long integre from arduino to arduino

Tags: arduino, communication, send

I need to send two separate integers from one arduino to another. There's no problem with the distance and communication, but I'm not sure how to do this.

I need to send the two integers, each from -15000 to 15000, in a matter of 0.2 seconds.

So one arduino is sending and another one is reading.

Answer (score 0):

You can try with Serial.print(int)
[look at this](https://www.arduino.cc/en/serial/print/)

sorry for my bad english

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have a serial link between the two items, you can

1) send it in a text-based way:

```
// Sender
Serial.print(value);

// Receiver
int value = Serial.parseInt();
```

2) send it in a binary-based way:

```
byte arr[4];

// Sender
for (i=0;i<4;i++)
    arr[i] = (value >> (8*(3-i))) & 0xFF;
Serial.write(arr,4);

// Receiver
if (Serial.available() > 4)
{
    Serial.readBytes(arr,4);
    value = 0
    for (i=0;i<4;i++)
        value = (value << 8) | (((int)arr[i]) & 0xFF);
}
```

The first way is easier, the second is more optimized and can become more reliable if you add some controls.

If you are not using a serial communication, you will have to change these functions (but probably any interface lets you send and receive byte arrays, so the second can be applied in almost any case)